# How to display pretty durations in Django templates?

Tags: django, django-templates

I'd like to write durations in my Django templates.
This duration would be the difference between now() and an input date in my view.

The hard part is that I'd like to do it in a *intelligent* way. For examples:

- if the duration < 60 mn, it should display "xx **minutes** ago"
- if duration > 1 hour and < 1 day , it should display "xx **hours** ago"
- and so on with "days", "months", "years".

Facebook posted news have this kind of behaviour.
It makes no sens to write "this news was posted 2567 minutes ago", right?

The question is, how would you advise me to do this in Django?
I was looking for a custom template or filter and didn't find anything.

What about custom tag? Or directly in classic Python method?
As I don't prefer reinventing the wheel, any lib or snippet is welcome, of course :)

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Django's [built-in template filter `timesince`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/templates/builtins/#std%3atemplatefilter-timesince). I think it does exactly what you are describing, if used without argument.

If you want a little more "human" time, for example "an hour ago" instead of "1 hour ago", you can try the [`naturaltime` filter from `django.contrib.humanize`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/contrib/humanize/#naturaltime), although it only works for seconds, minutes and hours.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thanks a lot! Would you know is there is a way to customize it? For example, instead of "3 months, 2 weeks", it would like to truncate this to "3 months" or better, "about 3 months"?

Comment: Looking at the source, `naturaltime` doesn't support time units larger than hours, so it doesn't seem to be a fit for your requirements (edited my answer). As for customizing, I think you have to create your own template filter. The [`timesince` filter](https://github.com/django/django/blob/faa8c71fd9e97794e73f7e7564446846d72d8bb2/django/template/defaultfilters.py#L784) is a good start, although the 'meat' of logic is in [`django.utils.timesince`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/faa8c71fd9e97794e73f7e7564446846d72d8bb2/django/utils/timesince.py)